# How to export a file to an output folder in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jar

I have a plugin, and I need to add files from the `.jar` to the data folder.

So far I have tried numerous times and yet no avail. The file in my jar is called `EffectList.txt` and the output folder is `plugins/MageSpells/EffectList.txt`

Comment: Is what you describe a one-time operation you need for some reason? Or do you want that to happen somehow during the building process, and by "output folder" you mean the location where your .jar goes?